# get specific lines from a repeated range pattern in a text file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, pattern-matching, range

What is the way to extract and save section of the text file between two delimiters.
I want to extract out section that begins with **first occurrence of string *"TYPE A"*** and **ends with first occurrence of "TYPE E".**

something like:

```
Some text, blah, blah, blah : TYPE A  
line 1 of text of my interest  
line 2 more text of my interest  
line 3 text of interest: TYPE A  
line 4 more and more  
line 5 more, now: TYPE A  
line 6 here is: TYPE B  
line 7 more and more text of my interest ...   
line 8 and now: TYPE E  
line 9 blah blah
```

I.e. I want to save to another file anything **in between these two delimiters** - first `TYPE A` including all consequent ones and the first `TYPE E`. It could exclude or include these two because I am really interested in further processing what is in between.
I would like to do this using sed or similar utility I could find on OSX or Linux, but not Perl.

Comment: Do you want to include the line containing "TYPE A"? Do you want to include the strings "TYPE A" and "TYPE E" in the output?

Comment: glenn - I did a small edit to clarify your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/TYPE A/{p=1;next}/TYPE E/{print $0;p=0}p' inputFile > outputFile
```

**Output**:

```
$ awk '/TYPE A/{p=1;next}/TYPE E/{print $0;p=0}p' inputFile
line 1 of text of my interest
line 2 more text of my interest
line 3 more and more text of my interest ... : TYPE E
```

Comment: I noticed that not everything after first TYPE E is being deleted using this code. I had to manually cut everything after first 'TYPE E'. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed '/TYPE A/,/TYPE E/!d;{/TYPE A/d}' file
line 1 of text of my interest
line 2 more text of my interest
line 3 more and more text of my interest ... : TYPE E
```

Comment: would you check my expanded example and see if it would work with TYPE As and other similar string occurring all the way until the first TYPE E?

Comment: @Edmon It saves all text after the first `TYPE A` until `TYPE E` except lines with `TYPE A` inside.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU awk, you can set a regular expression as the *record* separator. So if records are separated by "TYPE A" or "TYPE E", then you just need to print the 2nd record:

```
gawk -v RS='TYPE [AE]' 'FNR == 2' filename
```

Again, GNU awk.

Comment: It removes `TYPE E` and prints two empty lines before and after the record, but nice!

Comment: Good one, **+1**, but it includes the newline character after first TYPE match. It could be avoid including it in the `Record Separator` variable, like `RS='TYPE [AE][[:space:]]*'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/TYPE A/,/TYPE E/{//!{wfile3' -e 'd}}' file1 >file2
```

This reads `file1` writes the sections between (but not including those lines) `FILE A` and `FILE E` to `file3` and the remaining lines to `file2`.